# How can I create Json with this format in android?

Tags: android, json, soap

I want to send this serialize `Json` in `Soap` web service parameter to get data from server. I don know how to serialize `Json` like below.

I am doing this -

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                //obj.put("MeterSrNo", txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString());
                obj.put("MeterSrNo", txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("obj", obj);
                jsonObject.put("SPName", "XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And its giving me below output-

```
{'obj':{"MeterSrNo":"5"},'SPName':'XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail'}
```

But i want below output. How can i achieve this?

```
"{'\obj\':{\"MeterSrNo\":\"5\"},'\SPName\':'XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail'}"
```

Comment: Have you googled it?There's a ton of examples out there  http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/04/android-how-to-deserialize-both-xml-and-json/

Comment: This question could be resolved by 3 seconds with trivial googling of the subject, has no value at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON on Android - serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346786/json-on-android-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

By using [Gson Library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm) you can do serialization and desertification.

**Serialization**

new Gson().toJson(object)

**Deserialization**

new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);

Comment: Thanks Surya. Now i am getting below error-

{serializeNulls:falsefactories:[Factory[type=com.google.gson.JsonElement,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25@15bdd364], com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$1@3b93a9cd, Factory[type=java.lang.String,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13@3d29f282], com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter$1@12f1ed7e, com.google.gson.internal.Excluder@23f42e56, com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory@219a1ed7,

Comment: @MoinKhan r u using Date object ?                                                                                   same problem you can find the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114876/android-converting-an-object-to-json-format-with-gson-not-working

Comment: Still its giving same error. I am giving my code below-
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                //obj.put("MeterSrNo", txtMeterSrMo.getText().toString());
                obj.put("MeterSrNo", 5);
                jsonObject.put("obj", obj);
                jsonObject.put("SPName", "XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail");
} catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL).create();
            request.addProperty(parameter_getlistdata, (my).toString());

Answer (score 0):

Try following way,

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject jsonMeterObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonMeterObject.put("MeterSrNo","5");
        jsonObject.put("obj",jsonMeterObject);
        jsonObject.put("SPName","XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> Output

```
{
"obj":{
"MeterSrNo":"5"
},
"SPName":"XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail"
}
```